# Can I add pygame events from a second thread

Tags: python, thread-safety, pygame

Well I have read at various places that the pygame event handling must be done in the main thread. I want to do that but my question is, can I add events to the event queue from a different thread?

I want to call `pygame.event.post(myEvent)` from a different thread and than handle the event in the main loop. Is this possible?

edit: To clarify, I want to run a separate thread for asynchronous network i/o. When a new message arrived the thread would then put an event in the event queue to signal there is something to do.

Comment: I'm not sure, but why don't you try it & see what happens?

Comment: I will, when I get to it. The problem with threading issues is that it just might go wrong at some point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Time for some detective work!

Looking at the source for `event_post` in [event.c](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/d4452e3b1471604bb7e226b9606e8cb730e708e3/src/event.c?at=default) indicates that the C function uses the SDL call `SDL_PushEvent`, without checking for thread-safety on its own. However, the documentation for [`SDL_PushEvent`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_PushEvent) says:

> This function is thread safe, and can be called from other threads safely.

So it seems that it is indeed thread-safe.